# Trying to package posts for republishing by partner offsite

Tags: query-posts

I'm wondering if someone may be able to point me in the direction of a tutorial that can help me deliver my last X posts in X category as a javascript snippet to a publishing partner.

I want to be able to control the content (html) within the snippet without them having to do anything.  We'll be sending them posts and ads.  Would this be better accomplished using iframes?

Any advice appreciated.
A

Answer (score 0):

### Have you considered using the RSS feed to import posts?

Another possible solution might be to use [the export feature](http://en.blog.wordpress.com/2006/06/12/xml-import-export/), the output is an xml file though not js. I found [a program that will import the WordPress Exported file](http://gforge.devio.at/frs/?group_id=14&release_id=59) (which allows you to choose certain posts, all post, or posts between a certain date, or by category).

After you import the WordPress XML file you can generate; an HTML file, T.O.C, or a Word HTML file that consists of the exported file content. I'm not sure what your destination site uses to display content, but it should have a way to import the data.

Comment: HI thanks @Jeremy !  I did consider RSS but if I give them the direct feed i have no way to track anything about the content - how many times it was viewed on their site etc. Which is what I really want to know.  They are also using WP but the posts need to update in real time as they will be republishing from 1 - 10 posts /day. THanks again!